# GD image Splicing

Tags: php, html, gd

I create a large image,for a sequence of letters in one long line, (it needs to be in a long line initially), using GD library in php.  I want to splice the created image into many images of a stated width and put all the images into one image showing one under another.  Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: is there  functions you could recommend, or a way to go about it.  I'm not looking for someone to do his for me, just advice, as I'm new to GD so I don't no the full extent of possibilities yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be able to do that by
1) creating the new empty image with

```
imagecreate($width,$height);  (or imagecreatetruecolor($w,$h) )
```

2) opening the original image (the oneliner) with

```
imagecreatefromjpeg($path)
```

(obviously assuming it is a jpg)
3) cycling the original image "while it is not finished" and copying the pieces by using the function

```
imagecopy($destination_img , $source_img , $dst_x , $dst_y , $src_x , $src_y , $src_w ,  $src_h)
```

at each cycle you should change the dst/src coords ,to match the new "window" you choose to copy

you can find more info about how to use GD, here:
http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php